# Function for read a file

Tags: javascript

i've this function for read the content of a file.txt but the method reader.onload doesn't run. Why? I forget something? Tnk

```
function VediTesto(fileTxt) {
  var output = "";
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function() {

    output = reader.result;
    console.log(output);
  };
}
```

Comment: Because you never start the read?

Comment: How can i start it? @cHao

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its [in the docs!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText)

Comment: Why is this marked with PHP, JS and JSON?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start reading, with `readAsText`, `readAsArrayBuffer`, or the like. Til then, the FileReader doesn't even know what you want to read, let alone what format you want it in.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload for an example of how to tie it all together.

Comment: I add 'reader.readAsText(fileTxt);' after the }; but in the output i've the same. @cHao –

Comment: Assuming the file isn't actually empty, I'll need to see the code that calls your function.